# Mocha Best way to throw errors and test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I want to be sure that only integers are allowed as a parameter, so I wrote this test.

```
describe('Assigning values', function () {
  it('Should only be able to assign integers', function () {
    var item = new Item();

    expect(item.setValue('string').to.throw(Error, 'Not an integer'));
  });
});
```

And the function I'm testing

```
  var testInteger = function(num) {
    if (typeof num === 'number' && (num % 1 ) === 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Not an integer');
    }
  };
```

testInteger is called from setValue.

This test fails, and I'm not sure how it should be written.

Comment: `testInteger` is throwing an `Error` and the test is expecting a `TypeError`. Also should `character` be `item` or vice-versa?

Comment: @sheilak it should be updated now. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to.throw` expects a function as an argument, i.e. pass in the function to be tested, not the *result* of the function call. This ensures that the method is actually fired in the `expect` and the exception will be thrown.

The [example in the Chai documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#-throw-constructor-) is good, it just wraps the function to be tested (in this case `throw err;`) in an anonymous function:

```
var fn = function () { throw err; }
expect(fn).to.throw(Error);
```

So you could try:

```
expect(function(){ item.setValue('string'); }).to.throw(Error, 'Not an integer');
```

Also note the change I've made that the function under test is passed directly into the `expect`, then the `to.throw` is chained after that (location of parentheses).

Comment: Another option is the pass a bound function to `expect`, e.g.:, `expect(item.setValue.bind(null, 'string')).to.throw(Error, 'Not an integer');`